# Get blocklist from ghostery

Tags: privacy, adblock, ghostery

I am using Luakit as browser, which does not have support for firefox plugins like ghostery. It does have an adblock plugin which can use a textfile with all the urls that needed to be blocked, like easylist from the Ad Block Plus plugin for firefox.

I would like to get a textfile with all the urls that ghostery blocks, so I can add them to my textfile so my adblock plugin will also block those. Does anyone know if it is possible to get those urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to **install** Ghostery to get that information. After installing it in Firefox from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/ghostery/), the files you want will be in `your_firefox_profile/extensions/firefox@ghostery.com/chrome/content`. The files are: `ghostery-bugs.json`, `ghostery-click2play.json`, `ghostery-lsos.json`, and `ghostery-surrogates.json`.

Note that these are plain text files but are heavily formatted and will require cleaning up before you can use the data elsewhere in your other browser.

I suggest you rather use some other easily available lists such as the Tracking List from [here](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/fanboy-tracking.txt).

Another reason for not using the Ghostery list is that the way their data is stored changes with time. Some months ago, IIRC, they were in .sqlite format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have ghostery installed in firefox, but I think using fanboy's trackinglist is indeed smarter than parsing the ghostery list. I have added the list to my own blocking list. Do you know if there is a way to check if those trackers are indeed being blocked?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know that. Perhaps you can ask on Fanboy's forum?

Comment: That is probably the best way. Thanks for your time, I've marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug 9, 2013, the plugin for Chrome locates these files in

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij\4.1.2_0\bugs.js
```

It is still heavily formatted.

Answer (score 0):

For OS X users (as of 2015-12-30) in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/5.4.9_0/data/databases/bugs.json`